# Using EXISTS to fetch a row with a maximum value in a given column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, exists

Using the following query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   product 
WHERE  sale_price IN(SELECT max(sale_price)
                     FROM   product)
```

returns a row with a maximum value in the `sale_price` column of type `DECIMAL(35,2)` in the specified table `product`.

---

Can this query be rewritten using `EXISTS()` that can return the same result - a row from the `product` table with a maximum value in the `sale_price` column?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   product p 
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT max(pp.sale_price) 
              FROM   product pp 
              WHERE  p.prod_id = pp.prod_id)
```

Rewriting the query like this is incorrect and returns all rows from the given table based on the condition which matches every row in that table.

Comment: These queries are different. one says "find me every product where the sale price is in the values of this subquery that returns one row" and the other is "find me every product where there exists a row matching my exact same product id" which is effectively just `select *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood the `EXISTS` operator: it returns `TRUE` for each row of `product` where the subquery returns at least one row (which your subquery does for every single row, because a `MAX(...)` will return *something* if there's at least one row).

To rewrite the query with `EXISTS` you need to check that there does not exist an item with a higher sale price, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  product p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   product pp 
    WHERE  p.sale_price < pp.sale_price
)
```

The logic here is that if there does not exist a product `pp` with a higher `sale_price`, then `p` must be a product with the highest `sale_price`.